# Change Users Variables - Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi, build-automation, delphi-2010, automated-deploy

I am using an automated build tool called [Automated Build Studio](http://smartbear.com/products/development-tools/build-management/).

I have defined in the Delphi IDE, as you can see in the screenshot, a user variable `$(PLKFW)` which points to a specific folder in my computer.

**The question is:**

How can I change this `$(PLKFW)` variable **without** using the delphi IDE?

[image]

Comment: i don't understand your question. Do you want to know the location where the Delphi IDE store these variables to change manually this values?

Comment: I want an way of changing this variable outside the IDe, no mater how.

Comment: check this windows registry location `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\Environment Variables`

Comment: Yeah .. thats it. make it an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: @RRUZ Do you know if there is an way of changing this variable using a {$} directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Environment Variables defined in the Delphi 2010 IDE are stored in this windows registry key

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\Environment Variables`

just remember **be careful** when you edit this kind of IDE setting externally (without use the delphi IDE).